# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have the following code :

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;

public class LoginToThePortal {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
     {
    
    
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
         WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
         driver.manage().window();
         driver.get("");
         Thread.sleep(2000);
         WebElement username=driver.findElement(By.id("sfdc_username_container"));
         Thread.sleep(5000);
         WebElement password=driver.findElement(By.id("sfdc_password_container"));
         WebElement login=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"centerPanel\"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/button/span"));
         username.sendKeys("");
         password.sendKeys("");
    
          login.click();
         
        
    }
    }
```

And I have received the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable.
```

And I don't understand how I have wrong.
I will mention that I am at the begin. (I m still learning).
Can someone have a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Can you try with the below updated xpath's, Hope this will resolve your issue**

```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window();
    driver.get("https://qa-advisor.cs105.force.com/s/login/");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.xpath
           ("//div[@id='sfdc_username_container']//child::div/input[1]"));
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath
           ("//div[@id='sfdc_password_container']//child::div/input[1]"));
    WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath
           ("//button[@class='slds-button slds-button--brand loginButton uiButton- 
                         -none uiButton']//child::span"));
    username.sendKeys("test");
    password.sendKeys("test");
    login.click();
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and delete the screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

To send a *character sequence* to the *Username* and *Password* field you need to use [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use the following [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
driver.get("https://qa-advisor.cs105.force.com/s/login/");
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div#sfdc_username_container input[placeholder='Username']"))).sendKeys("Test");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#sfdc_password_container input[placeholder='Password']")).sendKeys("Test");
```

Browser Snapshot: